# Get ObjectId MongoDB via PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

Here's my script

```
$terms = ['username' => $uri];
$user = $collection->findOne($terms);
```

result

```
array (size=4)
  '_id' => 
    object(MongoId)[29]
      public '$id' => string '4ff6e96bb0b4599016000006' (length=24)
  'username' => string 'me' (length=10)
  'name' => string 'Yes, It's me!' (length=16)
```

**Get Name**

`$name = $user['name'];`

But, how can i get `$user['_id']` ?

I try `$user['_id']` NOT WORK

Please help. Thanks

**UPDATE**

Problem solved with `$user['_id']->{'$id'}`

Comment: What version of PHP and the MongoDB driver are you using?  Although the var_dump output shows your _id is an ObjectId, `$user['_id']` should still stringify to the public '$id' value (`4ff6e96bb0b4599016000006`) in your example.

Comment: this might help http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php

Answer (score 14):

`$user['_id']->{'$id'}` is not necessary and ugly, you can simply cast it to string to get id `$id = (string)$user['_id'];`