# Print MongoDB object _id in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am building a solution that uses a combination jQuery, PHP and MongoDB.  I have a php query that returns an array that I would like to print_r to a web page.  Everything works fine, expect I can not print the object _id, which looks like this.

```
$question_id = print_r($question->_id, true);
print_r($question_id);

stdClass Object ( [$oid] => 589625a3fef1fa3056501550 )
```

How can I convert this value to a string?

Comment: What if `strval($question->_id)`?

Comment: See this anser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378029/get-objectid-mongodb-via-php

Answer (score 4):

With new mongodb PHP driver just cast as string the `MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId` object.

[PHP object ref](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-bson-objectid.tostring.php)

**example**

`print_r((string) $mongoObject->_id);`

Answer (score 0):

For PHP 7 new MongoDB Driver

```
$question->_id->{'$oid'}
```